# Regex exclude trailing text from company names

Tags: regex

**CURRENTLY**

I am try to match valid company names from strings with 4 conditions:

1. the name can ONLY contain alphanumeric characters + spaces + hyphens
2. the name can contain a hyphen (inside the name)
3. there are company suffixes that should be excluded from the company name i.e. `Pty Ltd`, `Pty. Ltd.`, `Limited`, and `Ltd`.
4. If there are additional matches on the same line, these are to be excluded

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: ![https://regex101.com/r/Gpbdln/3]

My regex so far:

`(?:\s|^)([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?: Pty Ltd| Ltd(\.){0,1}| Limited){0,1}(?:\s|$)`

**ISSUES**

[image: ![enter image description here]

https://regex101.com/r/Gpbdln/4

It seems I am struggling with:

1. Excluding the suffixes to be ignored
2. Making the capture include spaces for the company name (while at the same time excluded suffixes)

I have been stuck on this for over an hour and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[\s-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*?(?=(?:\s+(?:(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|Limited|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).*)?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wvLuF/4)

If you only need to get matches that do not span across lines, replace `\s` with `\h` or `[\p{Zs}\t]` if supported, or `[^\S\r\n]`, to only match horizontal whitespaces.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?:[\s-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*?` - 0 or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of

  - `[\s-]+` - 1+ whitespaces or hyphens
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?=(?:\s+(?:(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|Limited|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).*)?$)` - immediately to the right, there must be

  - `(?:\s+(?:(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|Limited|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).*)?` - an optional occurrence of a sequence of patterns:

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - `(?:(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|Limited|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])` - any of
    - `(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|` - an optional sequence of `Pty`, an optional dot and then 1+ whitespaces and then `Ltd` string and an optional `.` char, or
    - `Limited|` - `Limited` string, or
    - `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]` - any 0 or more ASCII alphanumeric chars followed with a char other than whitespace and alphanumeric char
    - `.*` - the rest of the string
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: The example I showed, failed to specify that there might be additional text on the line that should be ignored. Sorry. Also "ignore." isn't a suffix pattern, I was trying to demonstrate that additional text after the valid match should be ignored. I appreciate the original suggestion and explanation.

Comment: @Wronski Just replace the lookahead with `(?=(?:\s+(?:(?:Pty\.?\s+)?Ltd\.?|Limited|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).*)?$)`, I edited the answer with explanation and a demo link.

Comment: I made a mistake in the desired behaviour. `A B C` on the 10th row should have been captured. You are amazing, and this is almost there. I may be able to finish it off myself even :)

Comment: @Wronski I am afraid that is something that does not fit all other matches logic.

Comment: thank you. I think I have enough here to work around corner cases. This is amazing.